# Fire resize event once on size down and once on size up

Tags: jquery, resize

So I have a function I want to fire ONCE when the browser is resized down to a certain point.

```
largeWindow = window.matchMedia( 'screen and (min-width: 650px)' );
jQuery( window ).on('resize', function() {
    if ( ! largeWindow.matches ) {
        jPM.on();
        jQuery(window).off('resize');
    }
});
```

This works fine, the function is only ran once, once we resize down past 650px.

The problem I'm having is resizing back up.

I want to fire another function once we've resized back up past 650px.

The only different would be jPM.off() instead of on.

The whole point of this is to turn jPanelMenu on when the browser is smaller than 650px and back on once the browser is larger than 650px. I guess another issue is I need this to happen over and over again.

Using jQuery(window).bind('resize.... makes the function fire over and over again as long as the browser is resizing. So jPM.on() gets ran like 50 times and keeps initializing the plugin, which is causing a huge mess.

Does anyone have any tips for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to use a 'flag'. In this case, I'm using a class to the html element

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/T7kDG/)

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ((!$('html').hasClass('small')) && ($(window).width() < 650)) {
        $('#output').text('small');
        $('html').addClass('small').removeClass('large');
    }
    else if ((!$('html').hasClass('large')) && ($(window).width() > 650)) {
        $('#output').text('large');
        $('html').addClass('large').removeClass('small');
    }
});
```

Of course, you could keep create a variable to store the status of the page (large vs small).
This example might be more 'visually' easier to understand.

[Here's an example with a variable instead of a class.](http://jsfiddle.net/T7kDG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use a timer. I do this a lot with window resize. I've found a 1/4 second to be a great time to go by!

```
jQuery(function() {
    var windowResize;
    jQuery(window).resize(function(e) {
        clearTimeout(windowResize);
        windowResize = setTimeout(function() {
            /*
                DO WORK
            */
        }, 250);
    });
})
```

## See Example

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone comes across this. A more modern way to approach this would be to use the [MediaQueryList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaQueryList) object rather than resize event, e.g.

```
const onMQLResize = (e) => {
    if (e.matches) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
const mql = window.matchMedia('screen and (min-width: 650px)');
mql.addEventListener('change', onMQLResize);
```