# how to avoid windows resize triggering multiple times which is triggered by other events

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I Found resize code in my page is triggeing  more than once during orientation change in devices. Suspecting this is due to other events like page scroll happening during page mode change from Landscape to Portrait and vice versa. I need to write logic in window resize but its calling more than once. Is there any way we can avoid other events impacting window resize

Comment: Because if, for debugging purpose, you unbind any other event, then the resize is fired only once?!...?

Comment: Note that the resize event is raised once for every *pixel* that the window size changes.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16595864/fire-resize-event-once-on-size-down-and-once-on-size-up/16596023#16596023

Comment: Use the `debounce` method.

Answer (score 1):

Window resize event fires multiple times during each window resize. As Rory McCrossan points out above, the event fires once for each pixel it changes.

An option is to use a `debounce` function, such as that described by David Walsh:

https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-debounce-function

Here is another useful article, describing the difference between throttling and debouncing:

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

Finally, you can use the less elegant (but equally effective) method of using a global variable to keep track of when you wish to allow the resize event to fire.

```
var ok_to_resize=true;
$(function(){
    $(window).resize(function(){
        if (ok_to_resize){
            //run your resize code
            ok_to_resize = false;
            setTimeout(function(){
                ok_to_resize = true;
            },500);
        }
    }); //END window.resize
}); //END document.ready
```

Comment: `debounce` is pretty much the same thing as your last example. they just wrap it a little neater and use the element's own properties rather than global var.